# How to read and display emoji and unicode sms responses

Tags: unicode, erlang, elixir, emoji, sms-gateway

I am developing a SMS receiver, which will do real time SMS receiving using Elixir. I have to get the contents of the SMS messages and store it into a MySQL database and display the SMS content on a web application. There I am able to receive English or Unicode messages. But I am unable to make it into text/ emoji when I receive Unicode ( UCS2 encoded ) messages. So I need to know how to make into a readable format, when I receive Unicode or emojis via SMS. I have attached a screen shot of SMSC deliver_sm packet capture for Unicode messages. Please support me to fix this issue? Thanks.

Current output of Unicode SMS ( Sample ) : �\r�\r�\r�\r�\u0000 \r�\r�\r�\r�\r�\u0000 \r�\r�

[image]

Comment: What is it the question? You get the data in UCS2, which you can interpret as UTF-16.

Comment: We need a little bit more info here. Particularly: How does the data look in your Erlang code? Is it a binary, a string, something else? And what does it mean "make into a readable format" for you? Print it out in the console? Saving it as text in a database?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I need to get the content of the SMS message and store that into a MySQL database. Also, I need to display the content on a web page. SMS will receive with Unicode, English and Emojis. Currently I have implemented this process for English language. But I am unable to read the content of Unicode / Emoji  SMS messages.

Comment: So, when you say "SMS will receive with Unicode…", what do you mean in Erlang terms? Will that be a string, a binary, or an iolist?

Comment: Have you checked this documentation? http://erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html

Comment: What does MySQL have to do with this?  Elixir has very strong support for all strings, and you can inspect any binary data, even if it's not a valid string.  Your pasted example included lots of �'s -- are those coming perhaps from values you stored in the database?  If so, I suspect you are using an improper encoding in your tables.